# Function works when called in main but not within another

Tags: c

I'm creating a resizing hashtable in C, and all of my functions work perfectly except for my `put` function when it calls the `resize` function. I can call the `resize` function directly from main, and I have no issues, but when I call it within `put`, the changes aren't reflected and only happen locally.

This is my data structure:

```
struct Table
{
    size_t totalLength;
    size_t bindings;
    struct Node **buckets;
};
```

This is my `resize` function which works perfectly when called within `main`:

```
static struct *Table Table_resize(struct *Table Table)
{
    size_t i;
    *Table newTable;
    struct Node *current;

    currentCount++;
    newTable = Table;
    Table = Table_new();

    for (i = 0; i < newTable->totalLength; i++)
    {
        if (newTable->buckets[i])
        {
            current = newTable->buckets[i];
            while (current)
            {
                Table_put(Table, current->key, current->value);
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }
    return Table;
}
```

This is my `new` function which returns a new Table of a size given from a global array:

```
struct *Table Table_new(void)
{
    *Table output = (*Table)malloc(sizeof(struct Table));
    if (!output)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    output->buckets = (struct Node **)calloc(countArray[currentCount], sizeof(struct Node));
    if (!output->buckets)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    output->bindings = 0;
    output->totalLength = countArray[currentCount];
    return output;
}
```

Here's my `put` function which seems to be causing the issues with resizing:

```
int Table_put(struct *Table, const char *pcKey, const void *pvValue)
{
    size_t hashIndex;
    struct Node *newNode;

    assert(Table != NULL);
    assert(pcKey != NULL);

    if (Table_getLength(Table) == countArray[currentCount])
    {
        Table = Table_resize(Table);
    }

    hashIndex = Table_hash(pcKey, countArray[currentCount]);

    newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (!newNode)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    newNode->key = (const char *)malloc(strlen(pcKey) + 1);
    if (!(newNode->key))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    strcpy((char *)newNode->key, pcKey);
    newNode->value = pvValue;
    newNode->next = Table->buckets[hashIndex];
    Table->buckets[hashIndex] = newNode;
    Table->bindings++;
    return 1;
}
```

Finally, here's my `main` function with the tests causing issues:

```
int main()
{
    struct *Table table = Table_new();

    Table_put(table, "1", "1");
    Table_put(table, "2", "2");
    Table_put(table, "3", "3");
    Table_put(table, "4", "4");
    Table_put(table, "5", "5"); /*this is where the resizing happens*/
    printf("%lu", table->totalLength); /*prints the original value(not resized)*/

    return 0;
}
```

Is there some sort of logic I'm missing here? I omitted any calls to free to make it easier to understand.

Comment: This declaration static *Table Table_resize(*Table Table) or for example this declaration *Table Table_new(void) does not make a sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow What is the issue with those declarations? The functions are supposed to return a pointer to a Table struct and take in a pointer to a table struct

Comment: Read a book on C how pointers are declared especially pointers to objects of structure types..

Comment: @VladfromMoscow My bad I forgot to include the struct part I changed it to that.

Comment: This struct *Table is also an incorrect pointer declaration,

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That compiles and runs for me. Can you tell me if there’s anything wrong with my functions ignoring that?

Comment: Why do you post scattered code snippets rather than a complete program?

Comment: @Armali I could post the entire program if that’s better but it’s really long

Comment: @SamLewis If that compiles for you then it seems I entirely do not know C. So I can not help you.

Comment: The whole point of having a ** in your structure is to avoid having to reallocate the whole structure when only the buffer needs to change

Comment: I'd draw a different conclusion: _If that compiles_, the language is not C.

Comment: Also, if you're going to reallocate the structure, you have to return the new one and use it outside your function

Comment: @MadPhysicist Oh ok - how should I do that instead? I also wanted to change things like the two variables but those could probably be done manually

Comment: @MadPhysicist I returned the structure in resize and new, would that not be enough?

Comment: Obviously not. If you call, `put`, and it allocates a new structure, you never use that new one. The code keeps reusing the old structure. You should always expand the buffer, not the metadata. Or at least update your references correctly.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Unfortunately I can't just expand the buffer without basically reimplementing my code from put, since I got my function headings as an interface. Once I allocate the new structure in put, however, how can I change the original to that directly?

Comment: Avoid sizing mistakes`output->buckets = (struct Node **)calloc(countArray[currentCount], sizeof(struct Node));`  --> `output->buckets = calloc(countArray[currentCount], sizeof output->buckets[0]);`

Comment: You don't have to change the interface. Just make `resize` return the original structure (and all the other functions besides `new` do the same). You're not obligated to allocate a new structure, just the buffer.

Comment: What's a `Node`?

Comment: It is very weird that `Table_new()` doesn't take any parameters, and instead gets the size of the bucket array from some global variable? Things will go wrong this way if you ever use more than one hash table at the same time in a program.